# Inject dependency based on php version

Tags: magento2.4, di

I use soap to do some calls to a remote server, php has changed method signature for `__doRequest` between php 7.4 & 8.x, is there any `di.xml` tag that can conditionally change the loaded class based on the php version?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Magento has PHP requirements for each release version and doesn't designed to solve PHP version with DI

Simple way is create custom factory for your class, create 2 classes with implementation and in factory `create` method check PHP version and returns correct one class instance. Use factory whatever where you need to use class

Example

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Adapter\SoapClient;

use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Factory
{
    protected ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $wsdl
     * @param array|null $options
     * @return \Acme\StackExchange\Adapter\SoapClient
     */
    public function create(?string $wsdl, array $options = null)
    {
        $class = 'Acme\StackExchange\Adapter\SoapClient';
        if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 80000) {
            $class = 'Acme\StackExchange\Adapter\SoapClient7';
        }

        return $this->objectManager->create($class, [
            'wsdl'    => $wsdl,
            'options' => $options,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

Always wants to find better and concise solution, but in some case works only some "classic" way.

After some tests I can confirm that solution with factory will not work properly with magento `setup:di:compile`.

Following example tested on 7.4, 8.0, 8.1

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Adapter;

if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80000) {
    class SoapClient extends \SoapClient
    {
        public function __doRequest(string $request, string $location, string $action, int $version, bool $oneWay = false): ?string
        {
            parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay);
        }
    }
} else {
    class SoapClient extends \SoapClient
    {
        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay = false)
        {
            parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay);
        }
    }
}
```

You pick incompatible parts and cover with version workaround and keep all compatible code in class like

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Adapter;

if (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80000) {
    class SoapClientProxy extends \SoapClient
    {
        public function __doRequest(string $request, string $location, string $action, int $version, bool $oneWay = false): ?string
        {
            parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay);
        }
    }
} else {
    class SoapClientProxy extends \SoapClient
    {
        public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay = false)
        {
            parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $oneWay);
        }
    }
}

class SoapClient extends SoapClientProxy
{
    // all other staff compatible with all versions
}
```

Comment: i attempted your solution previously, but the warning still pops up when i compile using magento setup:di:compile

Comment: You are right, with some workarounds i can compile with 8.1, but cannot with 7.4. See alternative in update